# What is the difference between target and executable in clion run/debug configurations?

Tags: cmake, clion

[image]

When I press debug button, The log show as below:

====================[ Build | luajit | Debug ]==================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/jack/CLionProjects/fluent-bit/build --target luajit -- -j 6
[100%] Built target luajit

Build finished

====================[ Build | fluent-bit-bin | Debug ]==========================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/jack/CLionProjects/fluent-bit/build --target fluent-bit-bin -- -j 6

Answer (score 2):

### Target

Target is build systen target (like [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#binary-targets), [here](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_default_target_statements), or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html#Rules)) that is built when you hit that *build* button.

### Executable

Executable binary file or script that is executed when you hit either *run* or *debug* button. That can be set to anything like `/usr/bin/ls` (doesn't make sense really), your own init&run script, or most commonly one of the build targets of the project (`fluent-bit-bin` in your case).

If *executable* is one of the build system targets other than selected *target* then CLion is clever enough to build that *executable* too before launching it. That leads to two separate log entrys being printed.

I think debugging makes sense only if executable is some of the build targets.

[Related documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2022.2/run-debug-configuration-application.html#config-tab)